# No logro cargar información en mi base de datos

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un grave problema ya que estoy tratando de cargar información a mi base de datos a traves de php, pero no se carga la información.

Cabe destacar que tengo 2 bases de datos, la base de datos alojada ya en un VPS y una de pruebas local con XAMPP, todos los desarrollos los hago primero en el server para validar que este funcionando correctamente y, en efecto, todo trabaja bien en este server local, pero al momento de trabajar en el VPS tengo conexión perfecta con la base de datos pues puedo logearme y consultar información, pero al momento de intentar insertar información a la base de datos no carga nada de información a dicha base, sin embargo toma los datos ingresados en el formulario, ya que parte de las funciones de este desarrollo es mostrarle en pantalla al usuario lo que digitó.

Pensé que podría ser un problema de privilegios de usuario entonces hice 2 pruebas:

1. Configuré los datos de conexión a la base de datos con el usuario root y sigue sin realizar la carga desde php
2. Con el usuario que configuré para el uso de este sistema hice un INSERT directamente en la base de datos para validar que dicho usuario si pudiese cargar información y en efecto puede realizar la carga de información.

Sin embargo les comparto un ejemplo de los códigos que utilizo para realizar esto en php, aunque creo que el problema podría estar más relacionado con el VPS, ya que en algun momento si me estaba permitiendo cargar información en mi base de datos.

```
require("../login.php");
$num_ot=$_POST['num_ot'];
$id_cliente=$_POST['clientes'];
$id_inspector=$_POST['inspector'];
$nombre=$_SESSION['usuario'];

$obten_idusuario=mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nombre_usuario='$nombre'");
$extrae=mysqli_fetch_array($obten_idusuario);
$usuario=$extrae["id"];

$obten_cliente=mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM empresas WHERE id_empresa='$id_cliente'");
$extrae2=mysqli_fetch_array($obten_cliente);
$nom_cliente=$extrae2["nombre_empresa"];

$obten_inspector=mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id='$id_inspector'");
$extrae3=mysqli_fetch_array($obten_inspector);
$inspector=$extrae3["nombre_usuario"];

$inyecta_ot=mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO ordenes_de_trabajo (num_ot,id_empresa,fecha_inicio,fecha_asignacion,id_inspector,id_usuario,status)
VALUES
('$num_ot','$id_cliente',now(),now(),'$id_inspector','$usuario',2)");

$trae_equipos=mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM equipos_bodegas WHERE id_empresa='$id_cliente'");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($trae_equipos))
{
$id_equipo_bodega=$row['id_equipo_bodega'];
$inyecta_equipos=mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO equipos_asignados (num_ot, id_equipo_bodega, fecha_asignacion, id_usuario, id_empresa, asignado) 
VALUES('$num_ot', '$id_equipo_bodega', now(), '$usuario', '$id_cliente', 1)");

}

$inyecta_movimiento=mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO movimientos (id_usuario,id_modulo,tipo_movimiento,fecha_movimiento)
VALUES
('$usuario',4,4,now())");

echo "<h2>LA O.T. No.: ".$num_ot." para el cliente: ".$nom_cliente."se asign&oacute; a: ".$inspector."</h2>
<p>Redireccionando a consolidado de ordenes de trabajo</p>";
```

Si es necesaria más información dejenmelo saber.

Comment: Hola. Qué dicen los logs cuando intentas insertar?

Comment: Hola @Alfabravo, disculpa mi ignorancia, pero desconozco como ubicar donde están alojados dentro del vps dichos logs, revisé el phpinfo para ver si ahí los podía ubicar pero nada, de igual forma intenté utilizar el mysqli_error($inyecta_ot) pero no me entrega ningun mensaje

Comment: No veo que estés controlando nada en tu código. Nombraré sólo algunas eventualidades, **todas** deben ser controladas. 1. ¿Hay datos vacíos en el POST? 2. ¿Hay conexión?  3. ¿Hay error en la consulta que lanzas? Todo eso debe ir controlado en tu código emitiendo mensajes adecuados en cada caso. Por otra parte, tus consultas son vulnerables a ataques de *Inyección SQL*, deberías corregir ese grave problema de seguridad usando consultas preparadas.

Answer (score 0):

disculpen las molestias.

Revisando a detalle el problema y espero que esto le sirva de solución a alguien a futuro, mi problema es que XAMPP no es tan exigente con el como configuras los valores predeterminados de tus tablas, es decir no te exige tener NULL o 0 o algo diferente a un registro vacio, caso que cuando importe mi base de datos de XAMPP a mi VPS no le tomé mucha importancia y bueno en resumen, lo unico que he tenido que hacer es especificarle a cada uno de mis campos que el valor default sea NULL y ya me está permitiendo poblar mis tablas. Gracias por su atención gente :D

Comment: Creo que en todo caso te refieres al motor de bases de datos que en XAMPP es MariaDB